# Delete txt files from folder and all contained subfolders

Tags: batch-file, text-files, directory, delete-file, subdirectory

I want to delete all .txt files from a folder, and all subfolders contained within, using a batch script.

I have a small snippet of code to delete from one folder, e.g.

```
del /s c:\MyFolder\*.txt
```

However this will only delete the text files from the 'MyFolder' folder.

Comment: Your command above will delete all `*.txt` file in `c:\myfolder` and in folders below it.  Is that what you want to do? Use quotes around `"c:\myfolder\*.txt"` if there are any spaces in `myfolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing drives:

```
pushd C:\Myfolder
if %errorlevel%==1 del /s *.txt
popd
```

It was searching in all subdirectories for all .txt files!

Mona

Comment: This is a dangerous way of using del /s because if the `pushd` fails because of spaces or any other reason (such as the drive not being mounted) then the `del /s` will merrily delete all of those files from the current folder and below - whatever folder that may be at the time.  The target path should always be fully specified or errorchecking done to see if the pushD failed.

Comment: You could check errorlevel before the delete to make sure pushd worked.